# PHP $_POST in form action not working

Tags: php, sql, forms, post

there is something wrong with the php post method, using php, the form code is the following:

```
<form method="post" action="keres.php">
    <select name="kategoria_keres" id="kategoria">
        <?php
            $kategoria = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT distinct mufaj FROM adatok");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($kategoria)) {
                echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['mufaj'] . '</option>' ;
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Keresés" id="keres" name="keres" />
</form>
```

The aim is to give the selected option's value using php $_POST method.

the processing php is the following:

```
<?php 
    include ("functions.php"); 
    include ("connect.php");
    $mufaj = $_POST['kategoria_keres'];

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM adatok where mufaj='$mufaj'");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . '<a href="series.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row ['cim'] . '</a>' . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['orszag'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row ['mufaj'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

When trying to print_r the $_POST it is empty, so this is the reason why the sql query returns with empty output.

The question is why does the $_POST not working, when the form passing it to the processing php?

Comment: print_r($_POST). you will know what is being posted

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @ developerCK: He already done that and it returns empty array.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Is it possible that $_POST is cleared in an included script file?

Comment: is that form submit redirecting to the correct page i.e keres.php and also the page in same directory folder ? I mean the both files one that have html code and secod that have php code(keres.php) should be in same directory.

Comment: Dont neglet harry's answer beacause i solved the same issue by doing that long time before. But I dont know Why sometimes selection box needs both id and name same....!

Comment: i tried with giving the same name to ID and NAME, and the problem is still occurs. The two files are also in the same dirs.

Comment: @Deepak Goswami - i am not getting any errors, simply get an empty page.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your   processing php file name is ="keres.php" because in the form action you set the keres.php.

Comment: hey, thank you for the answer, the processing php file name is "keres.php" :( de design loads in the keres.php, so the file itself exits.

Comment: then please set action tag as blank